# Can i have the same name for both vps server and domains?

Tags: domain-name-system, domains

Can a server name be the same name as a domains? Will this lead to problem when configuring server block?

Comment: please be more specific what is the BUSINESS RELATION in here? As currently i dont see this and thereforce it might be offtopic. End-User question like this, can be asked on superuser.com

Comment: @djdomi That's OK i will not ask anything again, thank for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the question is vague, this might be the answer you're looking for: Assume you have a domain name "example.com" which you have registered with a domain provider. You want to attach that domain name to a server called "www" so people can access a website hosted at "www.example.com."

When you configure the domain, you create a DNS "A" record which points to the IP address for the "www" host of "example.com." This is the "external" name of the server, the domain name. In other words, the FQDN of the server is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

The local machine "hostname" of the server at that IP Address can be "www" or anything else. Although it sometimes *can* be anything else, almost always, the internal hostname and the external domain name of the server should match.

So, with this example, yes, the server name can and should be the same as the domain's name of the server: www.

To find out what an internal server name is, in Linux, type "hostname" and it will show you the server name. In Windows, you can look at System information and look for Computer Properties, Computer name, or sometimes "Device Name"

Comment: Thank jared i appreciate the time you took to explain to me, now i understand.